# Table design - inner table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's my current fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/28/

I want to design the table in such a way that it looks like this:

[image]

How do a nest an inner table like the one mocked-up here?  I'm not sure that's even the right approach, so please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

colspan and rowspan.  A nested table will not align the columns unless you have absolutely rigid widths or very difficult JavaScript.

Caution, it can be hard to control the width of these columns.  Any 'width' for a td/th that has a colspan will be ignored.  Put the width on the first td in the column that has colspan=1.

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Sport</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th colspan="2">Pick</th>
  <th>Genus></th>
  <th>Genius Credential</th>
  <th>Result</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7">MLB Moneyline:...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4">[] MLB</td>
  <td rowspan="4">Sat 7:45 PM...</td>
  <td rowspan="4">The <b>Yankees</b> will...</td>
  <!--first row of nested table. It can be tricky-->
  <td>@-105 price</td>
  <td>chris</td>
  <td>MLB AL East...</td>
  <!--/end nested table-->
  <td rowspan="4">--</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> <!-- rest of nested table -->
  <td>@ -106 price</td>
  <td>sean</td>
  <td>...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>@ -105 price</td>
  ...
 </tr>
 ...
 <!-- repeat more rows -->
</tbody>
```